# Getting "No RestClientBuilderResolver implementation found!" when using RestClientBuilder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rest-client, payara, microprofile

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to use RestClientBuilder in my Java code to build a client with MicroProfile. I'm receiving the error message "No RestClientBuilderResolver implementation found!" Here's the segement that causes the issue:

```
MyClient myClient = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .baseUri(new URI(Url))
        .build(MyClient.class);
```

And here's my MyClient interface:

```
@Path("/root")
@RegisterRestClient
@ClientHeaderParam(name = "x-api-key", value = MyKey)
public interface MyClient {

    @POST
    @Path("/endpoint1")
    public MyObj getDeviceState(JsonObject body);

    @POST
    @Path("/endpoint2")
    public MyObj getGatewayState(JsonObject body);
}
```

I've verified that the dependencies for the necessary are correctly included. However, despite this, I'm still encountering the error mentioned above.

I am using Payara 6.2023.11, jakarta ee 10 and i am using the following dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-rest-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I tried multiple versions of them and also used them alone or together.

I also have tested to use

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClientBuilderResolver.instance().newBuilder();
MyClient myClient = builder
                    .baseUri(new URI(URL))
                    .build(MyClient.class);
```

and here I could go the the implementation of RestClientBuilderResolver which doesn't make sense to me.

I tried to do a small side project where I did the same and it worked. Then I added all the dependencies that were on my Main project and it still worked, so it don't think there is a dependency conflict.

Could someone guide me on what might be causing this issue and how I could resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!